# UILabel, UIFont and UTF-8 Triangle

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, unicode, nsstring, uilabel

I'd like to use "BLACK RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE" (U+25B6) as a part of my `UILabel`'s text. The label uses the system font (`UIFont`'s `systemFontOfSize:`). The problem is that my triangle is rendered as a fancy image, not a "black right-pointing triangle". Is it possible to see the plain version?

Comment: This seems to be a (controversial) "feature": some characters are displayed as "Emojis". Searching for "disable emoji in UILabel" gives some hits. See also https://devforums.apple.com/message/487463#487463 (requires Apple Developer login).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on:

[Unicode characters being drawn differently in iOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335724/unicode-characters-being-drawn-differently-in-ios5/8412044#8412044)

iOS 6 supports **Unicode 6.1's variation selector**, in this case `\U0000FE0E`. To answer my own question:

```
@"\U000025B6" // a fancy triangle (mapped to Emoji)
@"\U000025B6\U0000FE0E" // black right-pointing triangle
```

For more information check: http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.1.0/

Thanks @martin-r and @ACB, I wouldn't be able to figure this out without your hints!

Comment: That looks like a clean solution! I assume that this works only on iOS 6? Does the problem occur on iOS 5 at all?

Comment: I don't think I would have *ever* got there myself, thanks

Answer (score 2):

In case someone doesn't have access to that devforums, the below mentioned line is the reply from Apple.

> "With the set of fonts we ship in iOS, Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN has
>   the glyph you're looking for."

Try to use that particular font. That is the only way available now.