# How to get put the simple (non-themed) UTF-8 icons on screen?

Tags: ios, swift, utf-8

I would like to use UTF-8 for my icon buttons. The (default) play button is nice and not "themed" (▶), but the pause button is "themed" (⏸).

I am using the UTF-8 icons like this:

[image: Screenshot-2019-08-30-at-14-58-25.png]

Here the "play" (see the source code on the left) looks nice and is not themed (not in a blue button).

I do realize that the icons are from different sets:

- https://www.utf8icons.com/character/9654/black-right-pointing-triangle vs.
- https://www.utf8icons.com/character/9208/double-vertical-bar

Is it possible to show a simple (non-themed) version of the pause UTF-8 icon?

Is there another UTF-8 icon which could replace the themed pause icon?

Is there another way to put these icons there? Or am I forced to use images?

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15672714/1187415 what you are looking for?

Comment: This is indeed related and might work for some "emojis", but not for all emojis I am actually using: \u{FE0E} (is still coloured), \u{FE0E} (is still coloured), ⚙\u{FE0E} (is now black-and-white), ▶\u{FE0E}  (is still black-and-white), ⏸\u{FE0E}  (is still coloured). Are there any other ways to get nicer "icons" like these?