# Show row unicode character without emoji convertion

Tags: ios, unicode, character

I try to display unicode character without emoji on iOS.
I read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825620/uilabel-uifont-and-utf-8-triangle), but when I try it on some example, the result was like:

[image]

I output next code:

```
   str1 = "\u{25B6}\u{0000FE0E} " 
   str2 = "\u{25B6} " 
   str3 = "\u{1F310}\u{0000FE0E} " 
   str4 = "\u{1F310} "
```

How can I fix this? I expect that it will return raw white-black unicode character.

Comment: Could you figure this out?

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f310/browsertest.htm - like that (monochrome black-white sign).

Comment: So, did you fix this?

Comment: no, but i find solution, that works for my task with applying color filter on it.

Comment: Ok, good to put your solution here, so that it'll be helpful to the others, too. (:

Answer (score 1):

I can't find right solution, but for obtain grayscale image (in my case for background image for UIButton), we can draw this character and use color filter on it.

```
        var text = NSString(string: "\u{1F310}")
        var font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(22)
        var size = text.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : font])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        text.drawAtPoint(CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0), withAttributes: [NSFontAttributeName : font])
        var symbolRawImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(symbolRawImage.size)
        var fillCtx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        //Chose color for that sign
        textColor.setFill()
        CGContextTranslateCTM(fillCtx, 0, symbolRawImage.size.height)
        CGContextScaleCTM(fillCtx, 1.0, -1.0)
        CGContextSetBlendMode(fillCtx, kCGBlendModeNormal)
        var fillRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, symbolRawImage.size.width, symbolRawImage.size.height)
        CGContextDrawImage(fillCtx, fillRect, symbolRawImage.CGImage)
        CGContextClipToMask(fillCtx, fillRect, symbolRawImage.CGImage);
        CGContextAddRect(fillCtx, fillRect);
        CGContextDrawPath(fillCtx,kCGPathFill);
        var outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

So now we can choose right color.

Answer (score 0):

`str1 =@"\u25c0\U0000FE0E";` works for me.