# Convert C to Swift: Add magnifying glass icon to UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

How can I add a magnifying glass icon to the left of a `UITextField`?

I found an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811705/where-can-i-get-the-magnifying-glass-icon-used-in-uisearchbar) but I'm having trouble converting it to swift.

The answer:

> So, here's the code with the unicode character:
>
> ```
> UILabel *magnifyingGlass = [[UILabel alloc] init];
> [magnifyingGlass setText:[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:"\xF0\x9F\x94\x8D"]];
> [magnifyingGlass sizeToFit];
>
> [textField setLeftView:magnifyingGlass];
> [textField setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
> ```
>
> Edit: For plain look that fits iOS 7 style, add Unicode variation selector \U000025B6.

My code:

```
let searchIconView = UILabel()
// Doesn't work: searchIconView.text = NSString.init(UTF8String: "\xF0\x9F\x94\x8D")
searchIconView.sizeToFit()
searchTextField.leftView = searchIconView
searchTextField.leftViewMode = .Always
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two simple approaches:

1. You can use XCode to add Unicode symbols in your code directly (Edit->Emoji&Symbols).
2. You can use something like that

   searchIconView.text = NSString(unicodeScalarLiteral: "\u{D83D}") as String

(you have to use your character here)

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a specific reason for trying to add the icon as a UTF8String? If you have a magnifying glass icon as a PNG image, you can use the "leftView" property of UITextField like this;

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
let magnifyingGlassImage = UIImage(named: "magnifyingGlass")
imageView.image = magnifyingGlassImage
//arrange the frame according to your textfield height and image aspect
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 5, width: 45, height: 20)
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
txtField.leftViewMode = .Always
txtField.leftView = imageView
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift you can assign emoji characters directly

```
searchIconView.text = ""
```

Comment: How can I get the flat/plain version of this icon? (like the default one for iOS 9)

Comment: You can use any Unicode character. Just copy & paste it from the character palette.

Comment: @Code see my answer below for using the System icon which what you are looking for I believe.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated for Swift 5** and using the System magnifying glass:

```
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    let magnifyingGlassImage = UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass", withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(weight: .regular))?.withTintColor(.systemYellow, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
    imageView.image = magnifyingGlassImage
    //arrange the frame according to your textfield height and image aspect
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 5, width: 45, height: 20)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    txtField.leftViewMode = .always
    textField.leftView = imageView
```