# Can I place built-in magnifying glass character in UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Native search (or tables at the top of the table view index) have a nice magnifying glass icon.

[image]

Can I place same character in UITextField?

this approach doesnt' work:

```
self.searchTextField.placeholder = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", UITableViewIndexSearch];
```

[image]

Comment: You can use a Unicode character. More info about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036038/is-there-unicode-glyph-symbol-to-represent-search

Comment: @the4kman it's other character

Comment: Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883946/ios-programmatically-add-left-image-to-uitextfield-in-xcode

Comment: @aNa12 I don't want to use image. if it possible I want to use built-in character

Comment: What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056705/convert-c-to-swift-add-magnifying-glass-icon-to-uitextfield